# Add to Perl hash yields puzzling results

Tags: perl, debugging, hashmap

I am somewhat new to Perl, and this bug has puzzled me for a couple of days. I've had difficulty finding anything on Google for a problem this specific. I will try to present the "clues" as clearly as possible. I am using Perl v5.16.1. The relevant lines in my code are these:

```
my %result = ();

...

$result{'TABLENAME'} = $tableName;

...

for my $i (1..$numberOfColumns) {
    $result{$columnNames[$i-1]} = $columnValues[$i-1];
}
```

In my test, `$numberOfColumns` is 7. The problem is that the for-loop does not create the key-value pairs as I expect. I will explain. I've tried debugging using Perl's debugger with `perl -d`. The debugger output below shows things going fine until the last line.

```
  DB<2> c 219
testcode::testsub(modules/testcode.pm:219):
219:        $result{'TABLENAME'} = $tableName;

  DB<3> c 239
testcode::testsub(modules/testcode.pm:239):
239:        for my $i (1..$numberOfColumns) {

  DB<4> p %result
TABLENAMEmyowntableitis

  DB<5> p $result{TABLENAME}
myowntableitis

  DB<6> s
testcode::testsub(modules/testcode.pm:240):
240:            $result{$columnNames[$i-1]} = $columnValues[$i-1];

  DB<6> p $i
1

  DB<7> p $columnNames[0]
id

  DB<8> p $columnValues[0]
1

  DB<9> s
testcode::testsub(modules/testcode.pm:240):
240:            $result{$columnNames[$i-1]} = $columnValues[$i-1];

  DB<9> p $i
2

  DB<10> p %result
TABLENAMEmyowntableitisid
1

  DB<11> p $result{TABLENAME}
    myowntableitis

  DB<12> p $result{id}

  DB<13>
```

I expected the last `p $result{id}` to return 1 instead of nothing. Does anyone have an idea what could be happening here?

Comment: Give us code that actually produces the problem!!! Or at least, give the output of `use Data::Djmper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper(\@columnNames, \@columnValues)); }`. Best guess, `$columnNames[0] ne "id"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at `DB<10>`, we see that the `1` is printed on the next line:

```
DB<10> p %result
TABLENAMEmyowntableitisid
1
```

This means that `$result{"id\n"} eq "1"`, and you are using an undefined key.

A style note: `foreach`ing over two arrays to build a hash is possible, of course. But then again, Perl has *slices*, which makes life much easier (unless you are processing incredible large amounts of data)

```
@result{@columnNames} = @columnValues;
```

(assuming `@columnNames <= @columnValues`)

Comment: Thanks! Helpful pointer at exactly the clue that I had missed, what more could I ask for. :) When I wrote the foreach over two arrays, I kinda felt Perl must have something smarter to deal with this, but I didn't find out what. Thanks for letting me know about slices!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `columnnames[0]` is set to `"id\n"` and not just `id`. Notice the newline after the id. I guess you were reading these from a file and not removing the newlines. The same is true for the values. Add to your loop:

```
chomp $columnNames[$i-1];
chomp $columnValues[$i-1];
```

and that should fix your problem. Alternatively, you could chomp the values when you read them from the file.

On a side note, it's customary to have the loop counter be the index itself. That is loop from `0` to `$numberOfColumns - 1` or (even to `$#columnNames`).

Answer (score 1):

If `$result{id}` is empty, what does `$result{"id\n"}` return? You might be not [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp)ing the lines.